# Semantic UI unable to get text and value from multiple selections dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I populate my multiple selections dropdowns with API. The problem is that I can't get det text or value when pressing a button. What am I doing wrong?!
Opt 1 is the way I have implemented it. Opt 2 is the only way i can get a value but that it, everything else is not working.

HTML

```
<!-- Opt 1 -->
<select id="drp1" class="ui fluid multiple selection dropdown opt1" multiple="">
</select>
<button id="btn1">Btn 1</button>
<button id="btn11">Btn 11</button>
<hr>

<!-- Opt 2 -->
<div id="drp2" class="ui fluid multiple selection dropdown opt2" multiple="">
</div>
<button id="btn2">Btn 2</button>
```

JS

```
a = {'values': [
  {'name': 'a', 'value':'1', 'text': 'a'},
  {'name': 'b', 'value':'2', 'text': 'b'},
  {'name': 'c', 'value':'3', 'text': 'c'},
]}

$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
$(".ui.dropdown.opt1").dropdown('setup menu', a);
$(".ui.dropdown.opt1").dropdown('set selected', ['a','c']);

$(".ui.dropdown.opt2").dropdown('setup menu', a);
$(".ui.dropdown.opt2").dropdown('set selected', ['a','c']);

$('#btn1').click(function(){
    var tmp = $('.ui.dropdown.opt1').dropdown('get value');
  var tmp2 = $('.ui.dropdown.opt1').dropdown('get text');
  alert(tmp + " || " + tmp2);
});

// I can get the value by adding a but not text
$('#btn11').click(function(){
    var tmp = $('.ui.dropdown.opt1 a').dropdown('get value');
  var tmp2 = $('.ui.dropdown.opt1 a').dropdown('get text');
  alert(tmp + " || " + tmp2);
});


$('#btn2').click(function(){
    var tmp = $('.ui.dropdown.opt2').dropdown('get value');
  var tmp2 = $('.ui.dropdown.opt2').dropdown('get text');
  alert(tmp + " || " + tmp2);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3ubhp84/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in Aurelia:

form.html:

```
<select id="thickness" name="thick"  multiple="" class="ui multiple dropdown selection" value.bind="thickness_selected">
     <option value="">Выбрать</option>
     <option value="100">100 mm</option>
     <option value="150">150 mm</option>
</select>
```

form.ts:

```
export class form {

    thickness_selected: number[] = [];

submit() {
        const self = this;
        for (let id of self.thickness_selected) {
            console.log(id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation what Aurelia is.